# HTML pattern validation always false

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to perform a client-side check for a password insertion form in HTML, I need the password to contain at least an alphabetic character and a number. I tried with the following:

```
<input type="password" name="reg-password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" title="The password must contain at least a number and an alphabetic character" required>
```

but for some reason which I'm not understanding the validation always fails and I cannot submit the form. Could you please explain me where my code is wrong? I also tested the regex with some online regex debuggers and it should be ok. Thanks in advance.

Also, is there any particular reason for which I should avoid this methods of client-side validation and use Javascript code instead? I find this way much faster (if it only worked)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [HTML5 input pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-pattern-attribute) requires a full string match, use the following:

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+"
```

It will get translated to `/^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+)$/` regex and will correctly handle the input.

In case you are using some additional frameworks that override HTML5 pattern attribute handling, add the anchors explicitly:

```
pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$"
```

and it will work in all contexts.

JS demo:

```html
<form>
<input type="password" name="reg-password" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+" title="The password must contain at least a number and an alphabetic character" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! So if I'm understanding well HTML5 expected, with the previous regex, no characters at all and this was the reason for which the validation was always failing, right? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it expected an empty string but also required a digit and a letter, so, your regex was `^(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]))$` - a regex that will never match any string.